# PHP/MySQL picky about data selecting

Tags: php, mysql

Ive ran into a bit of a problem. Im trying to pull data from a column in which values in rows are the same. Ive use `SELECT * FROM teams where number=$number`  Where `$number` is specified by the user. It works on some rows,but some not. Its very weird.

http://pastebin.com/4CK3mmpd

```
<link rel='icon' href='/image/database_accepted.png' />
<body style="background-color:black">
<?php
   include 'includes/connect.php';
    //Include the login varibles

    //Setup a query for all teams into a varible

    $number_select = $_GET['team'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE number='$number_select'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     if($test==null){
        echo "<img src='/image/no_data_found_paramaters.png'>";
    }else{
        }
?>

<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<?php
echo "<table bgcolor='#00FF00'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Team Name</th>";
echo "<th>Team Number</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<font color='red'>";
    while($team = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>" . $team['Name'] . "</td>";
echo    "<td>" . $team['Number'] . "</td>";
echo   "</tr>";


    }
?>
```

EDIT: Requested operation paste:

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Number` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: [Your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Drew, probably. this isnt a corporate website, Juts a HS robotics scouting DB.

Comment: please run `show create table teams` and paste results under [edit]

Comment: just saying. someone could take it down. Just so you know.

Comment: @Drew will do,and I do appreciate the info. Will look into it

Comment: @Drew Do I run this in the PHP page or in MySQL console

Comment: Ok. Let me paste it. got it now

Comment: It will not let me copy the information.

Comment: right click MARK hit enter, or hand type it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change over to a safe library like mysqli or pdo, and use them in proper ways. See this wildly popular [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Not that that was your problem. You were never getting your first row due to calling `fetch` twice (the first time outside of the `while`).

So if you had no duplicates for a number, then the only row to fetch was already fetched and never made it into the while loop. In the schema below, number 9 would only show 2, not 3, rows in the html table. You get the idea.

Try this:

```
<link rel='icon' href='/image/database_accepted.png' />
<body style="background-color:black">
<?php
   include 'includes/connect.php';
    //Include the login varibles

    //Setup a query for all teams into a varible

    $number_select = $_GET['team'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE number='$number_select'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    //$test = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    // if($test==null){
    //    echo "<img src='/image/no_data_found_paramaters.png'>";
    //}else{
    //    }
?>

<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
<?php
echo "<table bgcolor='#00FF00'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Team Name</th>";
echo "<th>Team Number</th>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<font color='red'>";
    while($team = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo  "<tr>";
echo    "<td>" . $team['Name'] . "</td>";
echo    "<td>" . $team['Number'] . "</td>";
echo   "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Easily seen if someone mimics your data with this

### Schema

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Number` int(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)

insert teams (name,number) values ('aaaa',9);
insert teams (name,number) values ('aaaa',9);
insert teams (name,number) values ('zzzz',9);

insert teams (name,number) values ('blah',10);
```